# Authenticating with the new Google Analytics Core Reporting API and OAuth 2.0

Tags: api, bash, google-analytics, oauth-2.0

Google Analytics's new "Core Reporting API" (version 3.0) "recommend[s] using OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests" ([citation](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataAuthorization.html#AboutAuthorization)). Its documentation, though, is very unclear about how to do that. (It says "When you create your application, you register it with Google" ([citation](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataAuthorization.html#OAuth2Authorizing)), but does a shell script count as an "application"?? If so, I should register the bash script at [the "APIs Console"](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataAuthorization.html#OAuth2Authorizing), which doesn't give any guidance on how to do so.) Using Analytics' version 2.3, I run a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# generates an XML file

googleAuth="$(curl https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin -s \
  -d Email=foo \
  -d Passwd=bar \
  -d accountType=GOOGLE \
  -d source=curl-dataFeed-v2 \
  -d service=analytics \
  | awk /Auth=.*/)"

# ...

feedUri="https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data\
?ids=$table\
&start-date=$SD\
&end-date=$ED\
&dimensions=baz\
&metrics=xyzzy\
&prettyprint=true"

# ...

curl $feedUri --silent \
  --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin $googleAuth" \
  --header "GData-Version: 2" \
  | awk # ...
```

How would I do something like this — a script that grabs whatever login token I need and sends it back — for the new Analytics?

(Incidentally, yes, I realize the results will be JSON, not XML.)

Comment: I don't need an entire script as above. Explanation would, in fact, be even better (so I can generate and modify a script as needed).

Comment: Reposted at http://groups.google.com/group/google-analytics-data-export-api/browse_frm/thread/d31118126fbd5485

Comment: In case you're interested, I answered this here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-analytics-data-export-api/browse_thread/thread/d31118126fbd5485#

Comment: Update: A coworker wrote a shell script, but it's AFAIK his copyrighted work, so I'm not posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script

```
googleAuth="$(curl https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin -s \
 -d Email=$USER_EMAIL \
 -d Passwd=$USER_PASS \
 -d accountType=GOOGLE \
 -d source=curl-accountFeed-v1 \
 -d service=analytics \
 | grep "Auth=" | cut -d"=" -f2)"

feedUri="https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga\
?start-date=$START_DATE\
&end-date=$END_DATE\
&ids=ga:$PROFILE_ID\
&dimensions=ga:userType\
&metrics=ga:users\
&max-results=50\
&prettyprint=false"

curl $feedUri -s --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$googleAuth"
```